# How to filter date events in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I need to filter data between two dates, a start and an end, to display in front only events that occurred between the selected dates ...

Product Controller method:

```
 async show(req, res){
        const { product_id, dt_ini, dt_fin } = req.params;

        let dtIni = new Date(dt_ini);
        let dtFin = new Date(dt_fin);
        dtIni = dtIni.toISOString();
        dtFin = dtFin.toISOString();
        let product = await Product.findOne({ product_id });

        if(product){
            product = await product.populate('event').execPopulate();
            await product.find({"event.timestamp": {'$gte': dtIni,'$lt': dtFin}});
        }else{
            return res.status(404).json({ error: `Product not found.`});
        }

        return res.json(product);
    }
```

Model Event :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const EventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_id: String,
    timestamp: Date,
    created_by: String,
    description: String,
    sale_price: Number,
    list_price: Number,
    has_discount: Boolean,
    url: String,
    warehouse: String,
    page_type: String,
    showcase:{
        name: String,
        position : Number   
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

Model Product :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product_id: Number,
    product_sku: String,
    product_name: String,
    product_brand: String,
    product_category: String,
    event: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Event'
        }
    ],
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

After MongoDB `populate()` I am receiving this error:

```
(node:3496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: product.find is not a function
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a conditional populate:

```
 async show(req, res){
   try {
     const { product_id, dt_ini, dt_fin } = req.params;

     if(!product_id || !dt_ini || !dt_fin) 
       throw "You must supply a product id with start and end dates!";

     const existingProduct = await Product
        .findOne({ product_id })
        .populate("event", null, { timestamp: { $gte: new Date(dt_ini), $lte: new Date(dt_fin) } })

     if(!existingProduct) 
      throw "Unable to locate any product events in that date range.";

     res.status(200).json({ product: existingProduct });
  } catch(e) {
     res.status(404).json({ error: e.toString() });
  }
}
```

---

Or, you can do an [aggregated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) query:

Here's a simplified **working playground**: https://mongoplayground.net/p/YGiywDCkR-2

```
 async show(req, res){
   try {
     const { product_id, dt_ini, dt_fin } = req.params;
     if(!product_id || !dt_ini || !dt_fin) 
       throw "You must supply a product id with start and end dates!";

     const existingProduct = await Product.aggregate([
        // match against the product id
       { $match: { product_id } },
        // lookup (populate) the "event" field with event data as "events"
       { 
         $lookup: {
          from: "events",
          localField: "event",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "events"
         }
       },
        // spread out the populated "events" field
       { $unwind: "$events"},
        // filter the "events.timestamp" with dates
       { 
         $match: {
           "events.timestamp": {
             "$gte": new Date(dt_ini),
             "$lte": new Date(dt_fin)
           }
         }
       }
     ]);

     if(existingProduct.length === 0) 
      throw "Unable to locate any product events in that date range.";

     res.status(200).json({ product: existingProduct });
  } catch(e) {
     res.status(404).json({ error: e.toString() });
  }
}
```

Although, be careful about using `$lookup` as it can be quite expensive.